# uninitialized constant PackagesController::RiCal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, icalendar

I am getting error while trying to create `ics` file please review my code whats wrong with this:

```
uninitialized constant PackagesController::RiCal
```

Do I need to include or something else?

```
def i_cal
  pack = Administration::MerchantPackage.find(params[:id])
  loc = pack.offering.merchant.address.to_s + pack.offering.merchant.city.to_s
 cal = RiCal.Calendar do
   event do
     description pack.subtitle
     dtstart DateTime.parse(pack.start_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
     dtend DateTime.parse(pack.end_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
     location loc
     add_attendee current_user.email rescue ''
     alarm do
       description "Segment 51"
     end
   end
 end
```

When I try `::RiCal.Calendar` it give me error:

> **uninitialized constant RiCal**

Comment: Do you have `ri_cal` in your Gemfile? Have you run bundler? Have you restarted the server after that?

Comment: thanks a lot it was blunder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gemfile:

```
gem 'ri_cal'
```

Then navigate to your app root and run:

```
bundle install
```

Once completed you should restart your rails server and IDE:

It looks like it's a case that the gem isn't installed or visible to your app.